# How to pass multiple variables in a loop, into a ajax json data.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following code, and I want to pass the value[i] into a data string in a json ajax post submit, Basically what I am trying to do is grab all the checked values in a form and put them into a existing json data string in ajax.

code I have so far

```
 var values = $('input:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get(); // ["18", "55", "10"]
//console.log(values);

var length = values.length;

for (i = 0; i < length; i++){
    console.log(values[i]);


}



 $.ajax({
type:"POST"
,url : $(form).prop('action')
,data:{
name:getValue($('label.name input'))
,email:getValue($('label.email input'))
,phone:getValue($('label.phone input'))
,fax:getValue($('label.fax input'))
,state:getValue($('label.state input'))
,message:getValue($('label.message textarea'))
,owner_email:opt.ownerEmail||'#'
,stripHTML:opt.stripHTML
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to add a key for every value? Or are you good just adding an array to the DATA argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable data, add a values key to it, then send it in your AJAX request.

```
var values = $('input:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get(); // ["18", "55", "10"]

var data = {
    name       : getValue($('label.name input')),
    email      : getValue($('label.email input')),
    phone      : getValue($('label.phone input')),
    fax        : getValue($('label.fax input')),
    state      : getValue($('label.state input')),
    message    : getValue($('label.message textarea')),
    owner_email: opt.ownerEmail||'#',
    stripHTML  : opt.stripHTML,
    values     : values
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : $(form).prop('action'),
    data: data
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your object first, then pass it like this:

```
  var obj= new Object();
  obj.name=getValue($('label.name input'));
  ...
  obj.values:values
```

etc

```
$.ajax({
type:"POST"
,url : "YOUR URL"
,data: JSON.Stringify(obj)
 });
```

THAT'S IT 
Good Luck